# Filesize increased while converting png to jpg using imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

I am trying to convert the png images to jpeg using `ImageMagick` (version 6.2.8) convert command. But for some images the filesize increases drastically.

The command I used was:

```
convert 16million-pschmidt.png -background white -flatten converted_16million-pschmidt.jpeg
```

The size was **56 Kb**. After conversion it becomes **2.9 Mb**
Please help. I can ignore such images if I get a way to check before hand that this image will become much heavier after being converted to jpeg.

Comment: Please provide some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try indicating a [quality](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) value. 100% quality jpegs are little better than bitmaps.

Comment: It might be image-specific. I suspect -background white -flatten might add a bunch of redundant data. It might be helpful if we could see the image and try it ourselves.